# Why is my while loop not working? I'm trying to print average salary from a linked list of employee details ( C language)

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, linked-list

I have written a code to enter the name, age, department id, company name, and salary respectively, of employees from a text file into a linked list. I made a function named
'averageSalary()' to calculate the **average salary** of employees belonging to a **specific company**. I am getting the output but it's not correct. I made a count variable to monitor how many times the loop ran but it is never equal to the number of employees in the specific company, therefore, the average calculated is also wrong. I'm having trouble getting a clean output of the average as well. I'm started learning about linked list and it will be a big help if someone can help me out with this. Thanks!

Here are the details of the file, it is called employee.txt:
'''

```
    Peter 30 1001 Apple 8000
    Joseph 50 1002 Oracle 4000
    Mary 40 1003 Samsung 6000
    Lilly 40 1203 Samsung 7000
    Tony 50 1002 Oracle 3000
    Jake 30 1005 Apple 3000
    Sam 40 1007 Samsung 4000
    Lisa 30 1300 Oracle 5000
    Kate 50 1200 Apple 6000
    Rick 50 1313 Apple 4000
```

'''

My Code:
'''

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct personTag {
        char name[20];
        int age;
    };

    struct officialTag {
        int deptId;
        char cmpName[20];
        double salary;
    };

   struct employeeTag {
        struct personTag personalInfo;
        struct officialTag officialInfo;
        struct employeeTag *next;
    };

    typedef struct employeeTag EmpTag;
    typedef EmpTag *EmpTagPtr;



    void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double 
    E_salary);
    int averageSalary(EmpTagPtr *s);


    int main() {
        EmpTagPtr start = NULL;

        char E_name[20];
        int E_age;
        int E_deptid;
        char E_cmpname[20];
        double E_salary;

                // reading employee.txt file
                FILE *fp;
                fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");
                //fp = stdin;

        while (fscanf(fp, "%19s %d %d %19s %lf", E_name, &E_age, &E_deptid, E_cmpname, 
    &E_salary) == 5) 
        {
            insert(&start, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
        }

        fclose(fp);


        averageSalary(&start);


        return 0;
    }

    void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double 
    E_salary) 
    {

// create an empty node
EmpTagPtr newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);

// filling in the values
strcpy(newNode->personalInfo.name, E_name);
newNode->personalInfo.age = E_age;

newNode->officialInfo.deptId = E_deptid;
strcpy(newNode->officialInfo.cmpName, E_cmpname);
newNode->officialInfo.salary = E_salary;

while (*s && strcmp(newNode->personalInfo.name, (*s)->personalInfo.name) > 0) 
{
    s = &(*s)->next;
}

// `s` now points at the `EmpTagPtr` pointer where the new node should be inserted:
newNode->next = *s;
*s = newNode;
    }

    int averageSalary(EmpTagPtr *s)
    {
        double average_sal;
        double total_sal;
        double current_sal;
        int count;

        //read a company name from user
        char Search_CmpName[20];
        printf("Enter an company name to search : ");
        scanf("%s", Search_CmpName);

        //traverse the list to search the company name
        EmpTagPtr current = *s;
        EmpTagPtr prev = NULL;
        EmpTagPtr tempPtr = NULL;

        int found = 0; //not found
        while(current != NULL)
         {
            if(strcmp(Search_CmpName, current->officialInfo.cmpName) == 0)
            {
                found = 1; //found a node
                count = count + 1;
                current_sal = current->officialInfo.salary;
                total_sal = total_sal + current_sal;
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

        if(found == 0)
       {
            printf("Company does not exist\n");
        }

        average_sal = total_sal/count;
        printf("count is :%d\n",count);
        printf("average salary : %lf",average_sal);

    }
```

'''

Comment: `int count;` That is an unintialised variable. So it can contain any indeterminate/garbage value. Accessing it results in Undefined Behaviour. Init with `int count = 0;`. Suggest turning up warnings on your compiler if it is not flagging that for you.

Comment: Read about adding nodes to a single linked list... In `insert()` you are trying to push the new node somewhere (in sorted order?) along the list... You'll need far-deeper understanding before you can do that... For now, PREpend the newly malloc'd node to the beginning of the list... (I'm sure there's more to find, too...)

Comment: @kaylum I initialized count, average_sal, current_sal and total_sal to 0. The program is working as intended. Thank you so much!